# Encryption messages in a queue between 2 dlls

Tags: encryption, c#-4.0

I'm sending messages between 1 dll and another, effectively posting messages onto the dll
 input queue and receiving a messages back from the dll output queue.

These two dlls are very tightly integrated. DLL 1 is a producer,and DLL2 is the consumer. 
 I want to encrypt the messages before they are sent.

What would be the best approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the DLLs loaded in the same process? If so, what makes you think you need to encrypt the data?

Comment: That's good point. I think they are at the moment, but won't be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use the wcf bindings with message encryption enabled